# What is the "explicit"'s equivalent of "imply"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, synonyms, antonyms

> ***Note***: The original title of this question was "Why is 'exply' not a word?

While considering the words *implicit*, *implicate*, and *imply*, it struck me that I can't think of an equivalent to *imply* for the word *explicit* (specifically one with the same Latin root).

Is *[explain](http://thesaurus.com/browse/explain)* the equivalent? It <strike>has</strike> *seems to have** the same Latin root, but doesn't have the full connotation of intentionally making something *explicit*.

<sup>* (***Edit:*** Thanks, Jason and [e.James](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18692/what-is-the-explicit-equivalent-of-imply/18701#18701), for the clarification on this)</sup>

Comment: -1: I really don't see this as a good precedent for questions. There are lots of potential words that are not words. How are we supposed to explain why something _isn't_?

Comment: @MrHen - Perhaps you could revise my question for me. "Implicit" seems like a conjugation of "imply", but where does "explicit" come from?  Which word is the origin word?

Comment: The NOAD etymologies of *[implicit](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1257346)*, *[imply](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1257350)*, and *[explicit](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1245655)* confirm that the words are all very closely related, going back to Latin at least.

Comment: @Renesis: Perhaps: What is the "explicit" equivalent of "imply"? Your question body could then stay relatively the same. Instead of asking why there is no word, you are asking what word you should use in its apparent absence. If someone just so happens to know where exply went they are likely to mention it in an answer.

Comment: @MrHen - Thank you, that's a good suggestion and I applied the edit. Sadly, I got another -1 in the meantime.

Comment: I think the original deserved a +1 (or at least not -1). In either case, it has my +1 now `:)`

Comment: @Renesis According to NOAD, *explain* does not come from the same Latin root. *implicit/imply/explicit* are all from *plicare*, to fold; *explain* is from *planus*, plain.

Comment: The meaning of _imply_ is "strongly suggest the truth or existence of something not expressly stated," while _implicate_ means "convey (a meaning or intention) indirectly through what one says, rather than stating it explicitly; imply." What should the meaning of _exply_ be, "strongly state the truth or existence of something" or "strongly suggest the truth or existence of something expressly stated?"

Comment: @Jason - I changed that from "seems to" to "has" because I doubted my doubt, but I wasn't sure how to confirm. Thanks!

Comment: @Renesis: With the edit, I have swapped my -1 for a +1. :P

Comment: I'm voting to close the question because then it can be deleted. I see no point in asking why "exply" isn't a word in the first place, and since the title change I see no point in the question continuing to be here. My reason, fwiw, is "not constructive", because that's what I think best describes "Why isn't xxxx a word?"

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Why are you voting to close based on the original title?  The question, modified, has a good answer.  What exactly is the concern?

Comment: @NickC: No disrespect to e.James, but I don't think it's a good answer to the question as now posed. Mainly because it's preoccupied with answering the original. You'd get something totally different if the current question were re-asked. Which is maybe what should happen - then this one could be closed as a duplicate of the new one, and I'd be happy.

Comment: It's English, just make it a word. Start using Exply, maybe it'll catch on. That's really all it takes in English.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While I agree with MrHen in the general case, I do feel that this particular question has merit. The answer comes down to the order in which these words evolved, and the nature of their Latin roots. Language is not an exact science (far, far from it).

The short answer is that the word *exply* (or, rather, the *meaning* that it would convey) already exists in the word *explain*.

The "im" words in your list -- [*imply*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imply), [*implicate*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/implicate) and [*implicit*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/implicit) -- all evolved from the Latin *implicare* (*im-* + *plicare*) which means "to in-fold" or "involve". The word [*explicit*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/explicit) has similar roots: it is based on the Latin *explicitus* (meaning "disentangled" or "easy"), past participle of *explicare* (*ex-* + *plicare*) which means "to out-fold or "unfold", making it the reverse of *implicare*.

The word [*explain*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/explain), however, has its roots in the Latin *explanare* (*ex-* + *planare*), which means "to flatten out", or "make level".

Based on these origins, there was really only one choice for the concept of *implicate*, since it literally meant *to fold in on itself*. For the opposing concept, there were two choices: *explicate* (to unfold), or *explain* (to make flat). Note that these words are still valid synonyms in English. From this position it seems obvious why the word *exply* never appeared: at the time when *imply* was evolving from its Latin origins in *implicate*, the word *explain* already existed.

To summarize, picture the words evolving in parallel (from left to right) as follows:

```
plicare + in -> implicare -> implicate -> imply
        + ex -> explicare -> explicate
planare + ex -> explanare -> explain
```

Given that *exply* would have the same meaning as *explain*, there was simply no need for it to enter into the language.

***Edit*** (in response to the modified question, and some comments):

> Is *explain* the equivalent? It has the same Latin root, but doesn't have the full connotation of intentionally making something explicit.

I would argue that the word *explain* does imply a direct intention to make something explicit. A person seldom (if ever) explains something without intending to make it very clear to their audience. Also, it does have a different Latin root. See above!

Comment: +1, Amazing answer, thank you!  This is exactly why I asked it.

Comment: Thank you! Though I think kiamlaluno may be on to something with his answer as well.

Comment: I dunno, I'm skeptical. Probably you know a whole lot more about this stuff than I do, but *NOAD* seems to say that all these words actually meant different things back then, and that *imply*, *implicate*, and *explain* all entered the language at about the same time (and *explicate* some time later).

Comment: *NOAD* would certainly trump me. I have no formal education in this, my argument is based on the information I was able to find online. To me, the *NOAD* dates indicate the first occurrences of these words in English, not necessarily the first occurrences of the Latin roots evolving new meanings. *Imply*, for example, had a stopover in the Old French *emplier* before it migrated to English. *Explicit*, on the other hand, came directly from Latin to English.

Comment: I feel like this punts the question a bit.  If explicit became explain, then why didn't implicit become implain?

Answer (score 1):

There are not nearly as many occurrences where *exply* would be useful as there are with *imply*, because you need to clarify what you imply much more than you need to clarify what you exply, so it is less likely to be coined in a language.

Comment: Sure, only there are plenty of words less useful than *exply* would be. Such as *aveniform*.

Comment: @Jason What does aveniform mean? I couldn't find it in any of my dictionaries.

Comment: [According to Wiktionary](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/en/wiki/aveniform), it means "having the appearance of oats". I can't vouch for it personally.

Comment: *Explain* is *nearly* the meaning I would expect *exply* to be, although I would expect *exply* to contain the connotation that something was made intentionally *explicit*.  If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of *exply* is already rendered with the verb *state* ("express something definitely or clearly in speech or writing").

Answer (score 0):

Forget trying for parallelism. Just use *state* or *declare*. Either of those means to make something explicit.

Answer (score 0):

*Exply* would certainly have a different connotation than explain, state, declare, or any other synonym you could come up with. Part of it is because in order to make something explicit, one does not need to use words. This would be relevant in a number of situations, particularly when discussing painting, film, theater, dance, or any other number of things where meaning is transferred by showing rather than telling.

In such a situation, I could easily envision saying something like:

> "Painter X's early work implies a sort of religiosity, using line, color, lighting, and pose to mirror religious symbolism and ritual. In his later work, which actually depicts specific Christian sacraments, that religiosity is not just implied; it's explied."

Now try to swap *explied* with any synonym you want, and it doesn't work. You either get extra baggage in the connotations that you don't want, or you get different definitions that change the meaning of the sentence wholesale. Either way, the meaning is changed and you don't get the sentence you want.

Ladies and gentlemen, we have a lacuna :-)

Comment: I don't know if it's a lacuna. *Assert* may also be helpful here, since it does not require speech, so if you don't mind giving agency to an inanimate thing such as a work of art, the art can *assert* (*signifiy*, *uphold*, *claim*, *contend*, *establish*, *entail*) a point. There is more nuance on the outward side so it's not surprising you need to pick among many. Interestingly, in formal logic, *imply* `A => B` **does** mean explicit certainty.

Comment: Sorry to keep rambling on, but the phrase *is manifest* kept coming to me so I found this: ```Even the most religious of Hopkins’ poems exhibit values that transcend the boundaries of his particular religious faith, and it is not necessary to share Hopkins’ religious faith to appreciate the artistic power and depth of insight into life that is manifest in his poetry.``` https://epublications.marquette.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1144&context=phil_fac

Answer (score 0):

Where explain, state, declare, or so forth are unacceptable, consider using the word "denote" instead.  It does not cover every situation, but it is helpful sometimes.  My example:

"I find it odd that the word “baptism” is used to describe the washing of hands in Luke 11:38 when we are so insistent that the word always **denotes** a complete bodily submersion."

I was trying to figure out if "exply" was a living English word before this usage of the word "denote" occurred to me.  Is this reasonable to the rest of you?

**Edit**: In response to Matt's example:

> "Painter X's early work implies a sort of religiosity, using line, color, lighting, and pose to mirror religious symbolism and ritual. In his later work, which actually depicts specific Christian sacraments, that religiosity is not just implied; it's explied."

Rather than using the terms "implied" and "explied" in this sense, why not simply replace them with "implicit" and "explicit." In doing so, you have rendered new adjectives from verbs which were in turn rendered from these adjectives.